# Is it possible to develop an application using phonegap plus sencha touch

Tags: android, cordova

I am new in developing native application . I want to develop an android application using sencha touch plus phone gap. Sencha touch for desiging userinterface and phonegap for accessing mobile hard ware . Is it possible to develop an application or not . 
  If possible please give me any demo application or application structure.

```
                                        Thanks
```

Answer (score 2):

An example of Contacts application using sencha touch and phonegap is found here.
http://www.sencha.com/learn/a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-with-phonegap/

Comment: ya  i gone through it but i want an example to develop an android application it is for iphone

Comment: since u use phonegap which is a cross platform mob app framework.. The same code should work for android as well.. Its just the HTML ,JS and CSS.. so there shudn't be any issues.

Comment: if u still want an example for android u can find here http://android.amolgupta.in/2011/07/hybrid-applications-using-phonegap-and.html

Comment: thanks for giving reply. i all ready went through that examples. my intensention is that i  need to develop an application which should developed userinterface using sencha touch and i need to access the phone hardware (camera , compass,etc) using phonegap.